# Efficient algorithm to sort file records

Tags: c, algorithm, file, sorting, data-structures

I have a file which contains number of records of varying length. What would be the efficient algorithm to sort these records.

Record sample:

000000000000dc01 t error_handling 44

0000000dfa01a000 t fun 44

Total record = >5000
Programming language c

I would like to know which algorithm is suitable to sort this file based on address and what would be the efficient way to read these records?

Comment: You say each record is more than 5000 bytes?  Or you have more than 5000 records, each of 20-100 bytes length?

Comment: Sorry, Files will have minimum 5000 records and maximum is undefined.

Comment: Do you really need to sort this file yourself?  Or is having a utility to do this enough?  If you are running on Windows, you could use the SORT command.  I successfully used this to sort files with a size of hundreds of megabytes.

Comment: @Patrick I really need to sort this file myself. This is one of the module in my program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the file is too large to fit into memory, then your only reasonable choice is a file-based merge sort, which involves two passes.

In the first pass, read blocks of N records (where N is defined as the number of records that will fit into memory), sort them, and write them to a temporary file.  When this pass is done, you either have a number (call it M) of temporary files, each with some varying number of records that are sorted, or you have a single temporary file that contains blocks of sorted records.

The second pass is an M-way merge.

I wrote an article some time back about how to do this with a text file.  See [Sorting a Large Text File](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=674).  It's fairly straightforward to extend that so that it will sort other types of records that you define.

For more information, see [External sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).

Answer (score 1):

Since the records are of varying length, an efficent method would be:

1. Read and parse file into array of pointer to records
2. Sort array of pointers
3. Write the results

Random accessing the file will be slow as the newlines have to counted to find a specific record.

If you've got a really big file, adapt the process to:

```
for each n records
   read and parse
   sort
   write to temporary file

mergesort temporary files
```

Answer (score 0):

In-place [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qsort) is one of the best generic sorting algorithm. Faster sorting is possible (such as bucketsort) but it depends on some properties of the data you're sorting.